# Where is 'docker networks' information is saved

Tags: docker

I just created a sample docker network 'docker network create mynetwork'.

And I am trying to find where this information is saved?

I tried searching for 'mynetwork' under /etc/ but don't see it saved anywhere on the disk.

How come docker retains the mynetwork upon machine reboot?

Comment: @LinPy my question is where is this info saved? Any configuration file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Linux OS with default paths database for that is located in `/var/lib/docker/network/files/local-kv.db` but that's binary file so it will be hard for you to read/modify that.

Comment: can we copy and replace this file in another system? I want all the docker n/w created in one system to be available on another system. which may have different docker version too